# Java Class Method, method invoke() and primitive types

Tags: java, reflection, methods

Let's I have method

```
someMethod(int, String)
```

and I want to invoke it by method invoke(Object, Object[]) of class Method.
Can I do it? If I can then how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, use `invoke(Instance of Object containing Method, 5, "foo")`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it as following:

`MyClass.class.getMethod(int.class, String.class).invoke(obj, 1, "hello")`

where `obj` is a instance of your class. 
If your method is static you can pass `null` instead of `obj`.